# Retrieve session content from DB if session value is not set with PHP

Tags: php

Im generating a menu dinamically from the database using a DB function. This function depends on the user profile. So when a user login, the function will paint the menu content like this:

```
<li>menu1</li>
<li>menu2</li>
<li>menu3</li>
```

The problem is that each time I access to one of the pages, the php code calls the DB function, so I want to store the menu content on a _SESSION value and use it until session finish.

So, I try this. If $_SESSION['showmenu'] is empty call the DB function showmenuweb() and assign the menu content to $_SESSION['showmenu'] and if its not empty then, just $_SESSION['showmenu']; content.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['showmenu'])) {
     echo "there is no menu on session";
     $_SESSION['showmenu'] = showmenuweb('ADMIN');
} else {
     echo "there is menu on session";
     echo $_SESSION['showmenu'];

}
```

Then I call the session content with:

```
<php

echo $_SESSION['showmenu'];

?>
```

But this code always call the function showmenuweb(), its looks like always the $_SESSION['showmenu'] is empty.

Any help will be apreciated.

UPDATED: This is the code:

```
<?php

include_once('init.php');

if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
    { 
        session_start(); 
    } 

echo  $_SESSION['showmenu'];

if(!isset($_SESSION['showmenu'])) {
     echo "there is no menu on session";
     $_SESSION['showmenu'] = showmenuweb('ADMIN');
} else {
     echo "there is a menu on session";


}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <?php
    echo $_SESSION['showmenu'];
    echo '<br />';
    echo '<br />';
    showmenuweb('ADMIN');
    ?>



  </body>
</html>
```

The html output shows:

there is no menu on session

menu1

menu2

menu3

menu1

menu2

menu3

Comment: Do you call session_start on every page?

Comment: yes, on each ones.

Comment: Your snippet is correct, your error has to be somewhere else. Do sessions work at all? Dont you accidentaly unset your session? ...

Comment: Have you checked that showmenuweb() actually returns what you expect? What do you get if you do `echo showmenuweb('ADMIN'); die;`?

Comment: yes, it returns. if I put echo. In fact it always all the db function.

A newbie question, does a SESSION value can store HTML content right?

Comment: a session value can contain anything you like, including HTML content

Comment: thanks. I just dont know why its failling.

Comment: Does "init.php" issue a `session_start()`?

Comment: yes it does also.

Answer (score 0):

I fix the problem by using two session variables.

First assign the db value $_SESSION['MENU'] = $row['SALIDA'];

Then I check it.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['MENU'])) {
          $_SESSION['SALIDA'] = showmenuweb('USER');
}
```

Thanks to all for the help.